Wrong check-in time from camera to system laravel backpack
I am doing a project using laravel backpack about manage in-out vehicle for bus stop. Problem here is the check-in time is wrong with the real check-in time from camera.
My CameraLogginOperation file:
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Operations;

use Backpack\CRUD\app\Library\CrudPanel\CrudPanelFacade as CRUD;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

trait CameraLoggingOperation
{
    /**
     * Define which routes are needed for this operation.
     *
     * @param  string  $segment    Name of the current entity (singular). Used as first URL segment.
     * @param  string  $routeName  Prefix of the route name.
     * @param  string  $controller Name of the current CrudController.
     */
    protected function setupCameraLoggingRoutes($segment, $routeName, $controller)
    {
        Route::get($segment.'/logging', [
            'as' => $routeName.'.cameraLogging',
            'uses' => $controller.'@cameraLogging',
            'operation' => 'cameraLogging',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Add the default settings, buttons, etc that this operation needs.
     */
    protected function setupCameraLoggingDefaults()
    {
        CRUD::allowAccess('cameraLogging');

        CRUD::operation('cameraLogging', function () {
            CRUD::loadDefaultOperationSettingsFromConfig();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Show the view for performing the operation.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function cameraLogging()
    {
        CRUD::hasAccessOrFail('cameraLogging');

        // prepare the fields you need to show
        $this->data['crud'] = $this->crud;
        $this->data['title'] = CRUD::getTitle() ?? 'Camera Logging '.$this->crud->entity_name;

        // load the view
        return view('crud::operations.camera_logging', $this->data);
    }
}`

My CameraService.php file:
`<?php

namespace App\Services;

use App\Enums\CameraTypeEnum;
use App\Enums\DirectionEnum;
use App\Helpers\Helper;
use App\Models\Camera;
use App\Models\InOutRecord;
use App\Models\TypeCar;
use App\Models\Vehicle;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\File;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class CameraService
{
    public function checkIn(mixed $direction, array $dataXml, mixed $image = null, mixed $imageVehicle = null): void
    {
        $licensePlate = data_get($dataXml, 'ANPR.licensePlate');
        $vehicleType = data_get($dataXml, 'ANPR.vehicleType');
        $timestamp = Carbon::parse(data_get($dataXml, 'dateTime'));
        $direction = DirectionEnum::coerce($direction);

        if ($this->isInvalidData($licensePlate, $timestamp, $direction)) {
            return;
        }
        $licensePlate = Helper::formatLicensePlate($licensePlate);
        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $timestamp = $timestamp instanceof \DateTimeInterface ? $timestamp : Carbon::parse($timestamp);
            $imagePath = $this->uploadImage($image, $timestamp);
            $imageVehiclePath = $this->uploadImage($imageVehicle, $timestamp);

            [$driverName, $driverID, $vehicle] = $this->getDriverInfo($licensePlate);

            $this->assignTypeToVehicle($vehicle, $vehicleType);

            InOutRecord::query()->create([
                'vehicle_id' => $vehicle?->id,
                'license_plate' => $licensePlate,
                'checkin_at' => $timestamp,
                'direction' => $direction,
                'driver_name' => $driverName,
                'driver_id' => $driverID,
                'image_path' => $imagePath,
                'vehicle_image_path' => $imageVehiclePath,
                'data_xml' => [
                    'checkin' => $dataXml,
                ],
            ]);
            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::driver('camera')->error('Không thể check in', [
                'licensePlate' => $licensePlate,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'direction' => $direction,
                'image' => $image,
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'trace' => collect($exception->getTrace())->except('args')->all(),
            ]);
        }
    }

    public function isInvalidData(mixed $licensePlate, mixed $timestamp, mixed $direction): bool
    {
        if (empty($licensePlate) || empty($timestamp) || empty($direction)) {
            Log::driver('camera')->info('===> Invalid data from camera', [
                'licensePlate' => $licensePlate,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'direction' => $direction,
            ]);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function uploadImage(mixed $imagePath, DateTimeInterface $timestamp): ?string
    {
        if (is_array($imagePath)) {
            return $this->uploadImage($imagePath[0], $timestamp);
        }
        if ($imagePath instanceof UploadedFile) {
            return $imagePath->store('in-out/'.$timestamp->format('Y-m-d'), [
                'disk' => 'public',
            ]);
        }

        return $imagePath;
    }

    public function getDriverInfo(mixed $licensePlate): array
    {
        $licensePlateRecords = $this->getLicensePlateRecords();
        $driverName = null;
        $driverID = null;
        if (isset($licensePlateRecords[$licensePlate])) {
            $vehicle = $licensePlateRecords[$licensePlate];
            $driverName = $vehicle->driver_name;
            $driverID = $vehicle->driver_id;
        } else {
            $vehicle = Vehicle::query()->create([
                'license_plate' => $licensePlate,
                'name' => $licensePlate,
            ]);
            $this->removeCacheLicensePlate();
        }

        return [$driverName, $driverID, $vehicle];
    }

    private function getLicensePlateRecords(): Collection
    {
        $key = $this->getKeyCache();

        return Cache::rememberForever($key, function () {
            return Vehicle::query()->join('vehicle_user', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'vehicle_user.vehicle_id')
                ->join('users', 'vehicle_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
                ->select('vehicles.id', 'vehicles.license_plate', 'users.id as driver_id', 'users.name as driver_name')
                ->get()->keyBy('license_plate');
        });
    }

    private function getKeyCache(): string
    {
        return 'license_plate_records';
    }

    public function removeCacheLicensePlate(): void
    {
        Cache::forget($this->getKeyCache());
    }

    private function assignTypeToVehicle(mixed $vehicle, mixed $vehicleType): void
    {
        if (empty($vehicle) && empty($vehicleType)) {
            return;
        }
        if (! empty($vehicle->type_car_id)) {
            return;
        }
        $vehicleTypeModel = TypeCar::query()->firstOrCreate([
            'name' => $vehicleType,
        ]);
        $vehicle->update([
            'type_car_id' => $vehicleTypeModel->id,
        ]);
    }

    public function checkOut(mixed $direction, mixed $dataXml, mixed $image = null, mixed $vehicleImage = null): void
    {
        $licensePlate = data_get($dataXml, 'ANPR.licensePlate');
        $vehicleType = data_get($dataXml, 'ANPR.vehicleType');
        $timestamp = Carbon::parse(data_get($dataXml, 'dateTime'));

        $direction = DirectionEnum::coerce($direction);
        if ($this->isInvalidData($licensePlate, $timestamp, $direction)) {
            return;
        }
        $licensePlate = Helper::formatLicensePlate($licensePlate);
        $timestamp = $timestamp instanceof \DateTimeInterface ? $timestamp : Carbon::parse($timestamp);

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();
            $checkin = InOutRecord::query()
                ->orderByRaw('checkin_at, id DESC')
                ->where('license_plate', $licensePlate)
                ->where('direction', $direction)
                ->whereNull('checkout_at')
                ->lockForUpdate()
                ->first();

            if ($checkin) {
                $checkin->update([
                    'checkout_at' => $timestamp,
                    'data_xml' => array_merge(
                        $checkin->data_xml,
                        ['checkout' => $dataXml]
                    ),
                ]);

                DB::commit();

                return;
            }

            [$driverName, $driverID, $vehicle] = $this->getDriverInfo($licensePlate);

            $imagePath = $this->uploadImage($image, $timestamp);
            $vehicleImagePath = $this->uploadImage($vehicleImage, $timestamp);

            $this->assignTypeToVehicle($vehicle, $vehicleType);

            InOutRecord::query()->create([
                'vehicle_id' => $vehicle?->id,
                'license_plate' => $licensePlate,
                'checkin_at' => $checkin,
                'checkout_at' => $timestamp,
                'direction' => $direction,
                'driver_name' => $driverName,
                'driver_id' => $driverID,
                'image_path' => $imagePath,
                'vehicle_image_path' => $vehicleImagePath,
                'data_xml' => [
                    'checkout' => $dataXml,
                ],
            ]);

            DB::commit();
        } catch (\Throwable $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::driver('camera')->error('Không thể check out', [
                'licensePlate' => $licensePlate,
                'timestamp' => $timestamp,
                'direction' => $direction,
                'image' => $image,
                'message' => $exception->getMessage(),
                'trace' => collect($exception->getTrace())->except('args')->all(),
            ]);
        }
    }

    private function decodeXmlFile(UploadedFile|File|null $file): mixed
    {
        if (empty($file)) {
            return null;
        }
        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        return $serializer->decode($file->get(), 'xml');
    }

    public function triggerFromCamera(mixed $code, UploadedFile|File|null $dataFile, array|UploadedFile|null $placeNumberImage, array|UploadedFile|null $vehicleImage)
    {
        // Nếu không code data file thì không làm gì cả
        if (empty($data = $this->decodeXmlFile($dataFile)) || empty($code)) {
            return;
        }
        $camera = $this->findByCode($code, false);
        if (empty($camera)) {
            throw new ModelNotFoundException('Không tìm thấy camera với mã là: '.$code);
        }
        if ($camera->type->is(CameraTypeEnum::CHECKIN)) {
            $this->checkIn($camera->direction, $data, $placeNumberImage, $vehicleImage);

            return;
        }
        $this->checkOut($camera->direction, $data, $placeNumberImage, $vehicleImage);
    }

    private function findByCode(mixed $code, bool $throw = true): ?Camera
    {
        if ($throw) {
            return Camera::query()->where('code', $code)->firstOrFail();
        }

        return Camera::query()->where('code', $code)->first();
    }
}`

My LogginCameraCrudController.php file:
`<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use App\Enums\DirectionEnum;
use App\Http\Controllers\APIController;
use App\Services\CameraService;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\XmlEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

class LoggingCameraController extends APIController
{
    public function trigger(mixed $code, Request $request, CameraService $cameraService): JsonResponse
    {
        // Xử lý dynamic
        $cameraService->triggerFromCamera(
            $code,
            $request->file('anpr_xml'),
            $request->file('licensePlatePicture_jpg'),
            $request->file('vehiclePicture_jpg'),
        );

        return $this->ok();
    }

    /**
     * Check in from Ha Noi to Hai Phong
     */
    public function checkInHN_HP(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // validate request
        $this->handle('checkIn', DirectionEnum::HN_HP, $request->file('anpr_xml'), $request->file('licensePlatePicture_jpg'));

        return $this->ok();
    }

    public function checkInHP_HN(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // validate request
        $this->handle('checkIn', DirectionEnum::HP_HN, $request->file('anpr_xml'), $request->file('licensePlatePicture_jpg'));

        return $this->ok();
    }

    public function handle(string $type, int $direction, ?UploadedFile $xmlFile, ?UploadedFile $image): void
    {
        if (empty($result = $this->getDataXML($xmlFile))) {
            return;
        }
        app(CameraService::class)->{$type}($direction, $result, $image);
    }

    public function checkOutHN_HP(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // validate request
        $this->handle('checkOut', DirectionEnum::HN_HP, $request->file('anpr_xml'), $request->file('licensePlatePicture_jpg'));

        return $this->ok();
    }

    public function checkOutHP_HN(Request $request): JsonResponse
    {
        // validate request
        $this->handle('checkOut', DirectionEnum::HP_HN, $request->file('anpr_xml'), $request->file('licensePlatePicture_jpg'));

        return $this->ok();
    }

    public function getDataXML(?UploadedFile $xmlFile): ?array
    {
        if (empty($xmlFile)) {
            return null;
        }
        $encoders = [new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder()];
        $normalizers = [new ObjectNormalizer()];

        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        return $serializer->decode($xmlFile->get(), 'xml');
    }
}`

My anpr_xml.xml file:
`<EventNotificationAlert version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.isapi.org/ver20/XMLSchema">
    <ipAddress>10.10.114.90</ipAddress>
    <ipv6Address>::</ipv6Address>
    <portNo>12674</portNo>
    <protocol>HTTP</protocol>
    <macAddress>54:c4:15:f2:a7:25</macAddress>
    <channelID>1</channelID>
    <dateTime>{{$dateTime}}</dateTime>
    <activePostCount>1</activePostCount>
    <eventType>ANPR</eventType>
    <eventState>active</eventState>
    <eventDescription>ANPR</eventDescription>
    <channelName>IP CAPTURE CAMERA</channelName>
    <ANPR>
        <licensePlate>{{$licensePlate}}</licensePlate>
        <line>1</line>
        <confidenceLevel>97</confidenceLevel>
        <plateType>unknown</plateType>
        <plateColor>other</plateColor>
        <licenseBright>143</licenseBright>
        <pilotsafebelt>unknown</pilotsafebelt>
        <vicepilotsafebelt>unknown</vicepilotsafebelt>
        <pilotsunvisor>unknown</pilotsunvisor>
        <vicepilotsunvisor>unknown</vicepilotsunvisor>
        <envprosign>unknown</envprosign>
        <dangmark>unknown</dangmark>
        <uphone>unknown</uphone>
        <pendant>unknown</pendant>
        <tissueBox>unknown</tissueBox>
        <label>unknown</label>
        <decoration>unknown</decoration>
        <plateCharBelieve>99,99,98,92,99,93,99</plateCharBelieve>
        <speedLimit>0</speedLimit>
        <illegalInfo>
            <illegalCode>0</illegalCode>
        </illegalInfo>
        <vehicleType>vehicle</vehicleType>
        <featurePicFileName>1</featurePicFileName>
        <detectDir>0</detectDir>
        <detectType>0</detectType>
        <barrierGateCtrlType>0</barrierGateCtrlType>
        <alarmDataType>0</alarmDataType>
        <dwIllegalTime>0</dwIllegalTime>
        <vehicleInfo>
            <index>0</index>
            <vehicleType>{{$vehicleType}}</vehicleType>
            <colorDepth>0</colorDepth>
            <color>unknown</color>
            <speed>0</speed>
            <length>0</length>
            <vehicleLogoRecog>0</vehicleLogoRecog>
            <vehileSubLogoRecog>0</vehileSubLogoRecog>
            <vehileModel>0</vehileModel>
        </vehicleInfo>
        <pictureInfoList>
            <pictureInfo>
                <fileName>licensePlatePicture.jpg</fileName>
                <type>licensePlatePicture</type>
                <dataType>0</dataType>
            </pictureInfo>
            <pictureInfo>
                <fileName>detectionPicture.jpg</fileName>
                <type>detectionPicture</type>
                <dataType>0</dataType>
                <plateRect>
                    <X>496</X>
                    <Y>808</Y>
                    <width>66</width>
                    <height>24</height>
                </plateRect>
            </pictureInfo>
        </pictureInfoList>
    </ANPR>
    <UUID>53845e3e-1dd2-11b2-9fe9-932e28ec1803</UUID>
    <picNum>2</picNum>
</EventNotificationAlert>`

If you want to see other files that relate to, I will provide them.

Did you set the timezone? Make sure the camera timezone & Laravel app timezone are the same. Steps to set the timezone here

I did it on app file:
'timezone' => 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh',
I think the problem is the way the system retrieves data from the camera and transmits it to the xml file is wrong
